# How to fix : raise TypeError("Error converting %s to a TensorShape: %s." % (arg_name, e))?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm newbie python machine-learning with tensorflow lib. I tried Linear Regression. I followed the instructions and am getting the

> raise TypeError (" Error converting% s to a TensorShape:% s. "%
>   (Arg_name, e))

error when running the commands:

```py
n_dim = X_train.shape

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_dim])

Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
```

Display console:

> File
>   "/home/huyhys/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py",
>   line 148, in make_shape
>        raise TypeError("Error converting %s to a TensorShape: %s." % (arg_name, e))
>
> TypeError: Error converting shape to a TensorShape: int() argument
>   must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'.

Comment: `and am getting the "raise TypeError [...]"` No, you're getting the `TypeError: Error converting shape to a TensorShape: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'.` Please read your errors and don't pass tuples where you should pass ints

Answer (score 0):

This is because `X_train.shape` returns a tuple, so `[None, n_dim] == [None, (shape_0, shape_1)]`. What `tf.placeholder` needs is `[None, shape_0, shape_1]`.

Working solutions below:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

X_train = np.random.random((28, 28))
n_dim = X_train.shape

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, *n_dim])

# OR

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None] + list(n_dim))
```

Comment: I tried again, and didn't understand why the code was running. Probably by spirituality